# SQL accessing child table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a task in which I'm using Northwind database to select only these products which category name begins with 'C'. Product details are in table Products while CategoryName is in table Categories and this is the only answer I came up with

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Products P, Categories C
WHERE C.CategoryName LIKE 'C%' AND P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
```

I was curious if I can do it without putting Categories inside FROM clause and connecting the tables. For me it seemed logical that I can access child table and use the values inside it smh, can you explain why it's not possible?

Comment: FYI, it's 2021 why are you learning that 1980's JOIN syntax? The ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for *29 years*. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: As for the question, you could use an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @Larnu I was shown both syntaxes and I didn't know that this one is outdated, thanks for information tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Correlated Subquery to achieve this:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM Products p
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Categories c WHERE c.id = p.id)
```

This subquery is "Correlated" in that the SQL in the subquery references the query in which it's contained. Very similar to a join, but we are down in the WHERE clause using the `EXISTS` condition.

`EXISTS` is nice since it doesn't care what is returned by the subquery. It only cares that ANYTHING was returned by the subquery. So that subquery could also be: `SELECT 1 FROM Categories WHERE c.id = p.id` and this query would still work.

Comment: Good answer, but if it *could* be `SELECT 1` why don't you do that? Why make it *look like* `SELECT id` is doing something if it is not

Answer (score -2):

You should be using JOINS not that type of syntax (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, ...)
But you can do this

```
SELECT P.*
FROM dbo.Products P WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories C WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(LTRIM(C.CategoryName), 1, 1) = 'C'
```

Join Products with Categories using an INNER JOIN which will only return the records that match. Add `WITH (NOLOCK)` when selecting from a transactional database so it does not lock users when attempting to run a transaction. I try to avoid `LIKE` when possible so in your scenario you can use substring to get the first character. The first argument is the expression, then start index and then how many characters you need to grab. `LTRIM` will remove white spaces from the left so even if your CategoryName accidentally has a leading whitespace or spaces it will remove them before running the substring. RTRIM would be unnecessary for what you need

Comment: *"Add `WITH (NOLOCK)` when selecting from a transactional database"* This is terrible advice. Especially if you aren't going to explain all the consequences and incorrect data the user could get. I suggest a read of [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @larnu I doubt its terrible. Incomplete maybe

Comment: No, I am standing by terrible.

Comment: I glanced at the article you mentioned and I agree with it. This is a simple query not a stored procedure, view, temp table... just a select so I would still do a NOLOCK.

Comment: Agree with @Larnu **definitely terrible.** `NOLOCK` can cause more blocking than it solves; can fail with an exception due to data movement; return *completely incorrect* results including but not limited to: reading rows or even whole pages multiple times or not at all; rows which fail foreign key, unique or check constraints, or which cause an entire join to double up. There's almost no circumstances when it's the right thing to do, `SNAPSHOT` is instead the answer to most blocking issues. Pretty much the only time to recommend it is on system tables, or when diagnosing a blocking issue

Comment: To top it off, `NOLOCK` issues are very transient, and are often dependent on being run in high concurrency situations, which is what you see on busy production servers, not development servers